# Solution Verification: Prove this using closure properties of regular languages.

Tags: solution-verification, regular-language

> Prove that this language isn't regular using closure properties of regular languages: 
> $L=\{a^{j+1}b^kc^{j-k}:j,k,j-k\ge 0\}$
> $L$ is over $\sum=\{a,b,c\}$.

**My Solution:** 

We define the homomorphism $h:\sum \to \{a,b\}^*$ this way: 
$h(a)=a$ 
$h(b)=b$ 
$h(c)=b$ 
And now we get that $h(L)=\{a^{j+1}b^j:j \ge 0\}$. 
Note: I know that this language is irregular and it's very easy to prove using the pumping lemma and here the question ends. 
 But I've been trying to do something as a challenge to reach the known irregular language $\{a^jb^j:j \ge 0\}$. 
But I got stuck trying to get rid of the extra $a$, I've thought of concatenating the regular language $\{b\}$, like this $h(L)\cdot \{b\}$ which still gives me the same language but $j\ge 1$.  

I haven't been able to think of a way of doing it using homomorphism, is there a way to delete exactly $1$ $a$ from that language? 
Would appreciate any feedback, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the fact that each [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language) of a regular language is regular. Suppose that $K = \{a^{j+1}b^j \mid j \geqslant 0 \}$ is regular. Then its left quotient by $a$, which is
$$a^{-1}K = \{u \mid au \in K\} = \{a^jb^j \mid j \geqslant 0 \}$$ would be regular, a contradiction.